# How to use tf.while_loop() in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is a generic question. I found that in the tensorflow, after we build the graph, fetch data into the graph, the output from graph is a tensor. but in many cases, we need to do some computation based on this output (which is a `tensor`), which is not allowed in tensorflow.

for example, I'm trying to implement a RNN, which loops times based on data self property. That is, I need use a `tensor` to judge whether I should stop (I am not using dynamic_rnn since in my design, the rnn is highly customized). I find `tf.while_loop(cond,body.....)` might be a candidate for my implementation. But the official tutorial is too simple. I don't know how to add more functionalities into the 'body'. Can anyone give me few more complex example?

Also, in such case that if the future computation is based on the tensor output (ex: the RNN stop based on the output criterion), which is very common case. Is there an elegant way or better way instead of dynamic graph?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66185202/14337775. I'm facing a problem where the gradients are None while implementing SimpleRNN using subclassing. I'm wondering whether I need symbolic loop or can I manage without it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What is stopping you from adding more functionality to the body? You can build whatever complex computational graph you like in the body and take whatever inputs you like from the enclosing graph. Also, outside of the loop, you can then do whatever you want with whatever outputs you return. As you can see from the amount of 'whatevers', TensorFlow's control flow primitives were built with much generality in mind. Below is another 'simple' example, in case it helps.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def body(x):
    a = tf.random_uniform(shape=[2, 2], dtype=tf.int32, maxval=100)
    b = tf.constant(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), dtype=tf.int32)
    c = a + b
    return tf.nn.relu(x + c)

def condition(x):
    return tf.reduce_sum(x) < 100

x = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0, shape=[2, 2]))

with tf.Session():
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    result = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [x])
    print(result.eval())
```

Comment: Good explanation. My problem is the `condition` I need is calculated after run the `body` once. So it is like I need to use the return value of body as a parameter for `condition`.

Comment: What you want is precisely what happens. The loop is `while(condition(tensors)) { tensors = body(tensors); }`, so the tensors you pass are updated to the tensors returned by the body each time, and then those updated tensors are passed to `condition`. The only time `condition` is called before `body` is the *very first time*, before the body of the pseudo-code loop above is entered. However, in that case, it's just about initializing the tensors you pass in `loop_vars` correctly. For example, you could pass the result of `body` as the `loop_vars` tensors to `while_loop`.

Comment: oh, with `loop_vars` I refer to the function definition of `while_loop`, which is `while_loop(condition, body, loop_vars)` (its the tensors that are passed to `condition` and `body`)