# Is it possible to loop through all minibatches in a single tensorflow op using dataset/iterators?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working with `tf.data.dataset`/`iterator` mechanism and trying to improve data loading performance.  It occurred to me that offloading the entire  minibatch loop from Python might help.  My data is small enough that storing on CPU or GPU is no problem.

So, Is it possible to loop an optimizer node over a full minibatched epoch within a call to `session.run`?

The tensor returned by `iterator.get_next()` is only incremented once per `session.run`, which would seems to make it impossible to iterate through a dataset of minibatches... but if it could be done, my CPU would only have to touch the Python thread once per epoch.

UPDATE:  @muskrat's suggestion to use `tf.slice` can be used for this purpose.  See my subsequent non-answer with a schematic implementation of this using `tf.while_loop`.  However, the *question* is whether this can be accomplished using dataset/iterators... and I'd still like to know.

Answer (score 1):

From the description it seems that you already have the dataset preloaded as a constant on CPU/GPU, like [at this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_preloaded.py).  That's certainly the first step.

Second, I suggest using `tf.slice()` to replicate the effect of the minibatch operation.  In other words, just manually slice minibatches out of the preloaded constant (your dataset), and you should get the desired behavior.  See for example [the slice docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) or [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596333/tensorflow-store-training-data-on-gpu-memory).

If that's not enough detail, please edit your question to include a code example (with mnist or something) and I can give more details.

Comment: Thanks @muskrat, this is helpful - I'm currently using dataset(batch) to create a iterator over mini-batches, but it sounds like you'd replace that with slice() and store local slice-position variables in the model.  What op do you recommend for the looping structure?

Comment: Cool.  I should add that I'm not entirely sure this will materially improve performance (but maybe that's just because I don't know the full context). I'd be glad to see what you end up with here :).

Comment: I'd  really like to see an answer to whether this is possible with datasets/iterators as in the title... I'm going to leave the question open, but for sure +1 for `tf.slice` and see my (non-)answer below for implementation.

Comment: Thanks for additional explanation, and good progress below (+1 for that). I’ll take a look later and see if I can come up with anything. Neat problem!

Answer (score 1):

This "answer" is an implementation of muskrat's `tf.slice` suggestion with the details of `tf.while_loop` worked out (with help from [How to use tf.while_loop() in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441140/how-to-use-tf-while-loop-in-tensorflow) and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop).

Unless your data and model are small enough that you're bottlenecked by Python I/O (like me!), this solution is probably academic.

Advantages:

- Trains over minibatches without returning to the Python thread.
- Uses *only* ops that have GPU implementations meaning that the entire graph can be placed in the GPU.
- On my small dataset, which is presumably bottlenecked by Python I/O, this solution is twice the speed of my dataset/iteratior (which touches Python once per minibatch) and four times the speed of passing minibatches through `feed_dict`.

Disadvantages:

- `tf.while_loop` is *treacherous*.  It's challenging to understand when ops inside the loop's body are evaluated and when those they depend on are evaluated, particularly the (thin) official documentation and limited Stack Overflow coverage.
- The missing documentation of  `tf.while_loop` is that *tensors outside the body of the loop are only evaluated once, even if inner ops depend on them.*  This means that optimization, model, and loss have to be defined in the loop.  This limits flexibility if you'd like to e.g. be able to call validation loss ops between training epochs.  Presumably this could be accomplished with `tf.cond` statements and the appropriate flags passed in via `feed_dict`.  But not nearly as flexible or elegant as the dataset/iterator mechanism in `tf.data`.
- Adding shuffling operations at each Epoch doesn't seem available on GPU.

Here's my schematic code (I've ommitted the variable and model definition for brevity):

```
def buildModel(info, training_data, training_targets):

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    # numBatches is passed in from Python once per Epoch.
    batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'batch_size')

    # Initializers for loop variables for tf.while_loop
    batchCounter = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
    lossList =  tf.Variable(tf.zeros([0,1]), trainable=False)

    # In a full example, I'd normalize my data here.  And possibly shuffle 
    tf_training_data     =  tf.constant(training_data,    dtype=tf.float32)
    tf_training_targets  =  tf.constant(training_targets, dtype=tf.float32)  

    # For brevity, I'll spare the definitions of my variables.  Because tf.Variables
    # are essentially treated as globals in the model and are manipulated directly (like with tf.apply)
    # they can reside outside runMinibatch, the body of tf.while_loop.

    # weights_1 =
    # biases_1  = 
    # etc.

    def moreMinibatches(batchCount, lossList):
        return (batchCount + 1) * batch_size <= len(training_data)

    def runMinibatch(batchCount, lossList):
        # These tensors and ops have to be defined inside runMinibatch, otherwise they're not updated as tf.wile_loop loops.  This means
        # slices, model definition, loss tensor, and training op.

        dat_batch  = tf.slice(tf_training_data,    [tf.cast(batchCounter * batch_size, tf.int32) , 0], [tf.cast(batch_size, tf.int32), -1])
        targ_batch = tf.slice(tf_training_targets, [tf.cast(batchCounter * batch_size, tf.int32) , 0], [tf.cast(batch_size, tf.int32), -1])

        # Here's where you'd define the model as a function of weights and biases above and dat_batch

        # model = <insert here>

        loss         = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(model, targ_batch))
        optimizer    = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer() # for example

        train_op = optimizer.minimize(while_loss, name='optimizer')

        # control_dependences ensures that train_op is run before return
        # even though the return values don't explicitly depend on it.  
        with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
            return batchCount + 1,  tf.concat([lossList, [[while_loss]]],0)

    # So, the idea is that this trains a full epoch without returning to Python.
    trainMinibatches = tf.while_loop(moreMinibatches, runMinibatch, [minibatchCounter, lossList]
                                        shape_invariants=[batchCounter.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape(None)])

    return (graph, 
           {'trainMinibatches'     : trainAllMinibatches,
            'minibatchCounter'      : minibatchCounter,
            'norm_loss'             : norm_loss,
           } )

numEpochs     = 100 # e.g.
minibatchSize = 32  # 
# training_dataset = <data here>
# training_targets = <targets here>

graph, ops = buildModel(info, training_dataset, training_targets, 
minibatch_size)

with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for i in range(numEpochs):

    # This op will train on as all minibatches that fit in the full dataset. finalBatchCount with be the number of 
    # complete minibatches in the dataset.  lossList is a list of each step's minibatches.
    finalBatchCount, lossList = session.run(ops['trainAllMinibatches'], 
                                    feed_dict={'batch_size:0':minibatchSize})

    print('minibatch losses at Epoch', i, ': ', lossList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented tf.slice() and tf.while_loop approach to vectorize mini-batch suggested above.

The performance was about 1.86 times faster in my case than the mini-batches using feed_dict, but I found there was a problem that the loss values of each epochs were not stabilized.

Then, I changed to tf.random_shuffle the inputs every epoch, the problem was much mitigated. (the performance gain was reduced to 1.68 times)