# Loop inside tf.function, impossible to compute gradients

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to compute gradients with respect to some variables defined inside a loop in a tf.function, however I always get a None result. Here is a basic example replicating the problem:

```
@tf.function
def problem():
  test = tf.constant(1.0)

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:     
    for i in tf.range(5):
      test1 = test
      tape.watch(test1)
      test2 = test1

  grad = tape.gradient(test2, test1)

  return grad

print(problem())    #None
```

Of course in this particular case I don't even need the loop. However in a more general situation I would like to store the test1 variable (and possibly others) inside a TensorArray (or similar structure) during the loop, and then compute gradients with respect to those. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Using `.range()` might work but I think when you are writing a `tf` operation, having `np` calls might prevent the operation from running on the GPU. However the problem was raised before, check [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41594).

There is two possible workarounds I can share. One of them is to use `tf. range` outside the gradient tape.

```
@tf.function
def problem(step):
    test = tf.constant(1.0)
    for i in tf.range(step):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:    
            tape.watch(test)
            test1 = test
            test2 = test1
        grad = tape.gradient(test2, test1)
    return grad

print(problem(5)) # 1
```

or run without `@tf.function`.

```
def problem(step):
    test = tf.constant(1.0)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:   
        for _ in tf.range(step):
            tape.watch(test)
            test1 = test
            test2 = test1
    grad = tape.gradient(test2, test1)
    return grad

print(problem(5))  # 1
```

Or, you can look into [`tf.while_loop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37444810/9215780).

### Update

`.range` is good to use. It won't create any major bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks. Using tf.range outside the tape isn't very useful as the loop is only a part of the code and I ultimately need to compute a gradient of something that is defined after the loop. Running without tf.function works but evaluates eagerly hence it's much slower when there are many steps.

Comment: Then use `.range()`.

Comment: tf.range() without the tf.function() has no effect on the running time. They are only really useful whey they are used together.

Comment: I see. I didn't observe the proper codebase. Typically in a custom training loop (whether `tf` or `pytorch`), it's common to use `for .. range(epoch)`. On the other hand, the graph model should compile much faster than the eager mode.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully explain why this works, but you can replace `tf.range` with `range` to get a desired result. Note that you could keep your original code but remove the `tf.function` decorator, and you would get the same result.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def problem():
  test = tf.constant(1.0)
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:     
    for i in range(5):
      test1 = test
      tape.watch(test1)
      test2 = test1

  grad = tape.gradient(test2, test1)

  return grad

print(problem())  # tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: yes both solutions work however they make the code much slower to run when there are many steps.